# Git switch branches in multiple packages simultaneously

Tags: git

Right now, I am working on a project with multiple packages, where each package has their own git repo. Is there a git command (or some plugin) that lets me change the branch of multiple packages at once?

For example, suppose I have

```
package a: branch mainline
package b: branch mainline
```

This command would then change the branches of both packages, so the result would be:

```
package a: branch features
package b: branch features.
```

Comment: git does not do that; you may look at "repo" script used in aosp

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in my case by using `find`:

```
find . -name '.git' -execdir git checkout <branch> \;
```

This is of course wrappable to your bash-hacker heart's content.